# Azure Managed Identity: DefaultAzureCredential: Regional Cache Auth Service token requests for flows that require encrypted tokens are forbidden

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, token, azure-managed-identity

I have a C# / .NET Core Azure Function with a system managed identity. I want to use this identity to get a token to interact with another service. For this I use DefaultAzureCredential -> GetTokenAsync from Azure.Identity.

But when I try that I get the following error:

> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request
> failed.\nStatus: 400 (Bad
> Request)\n\nContent:\n{"exceptionMessage":"AADSTS100009: Regional
> Cache Auth Service token requests for flows that require encrypted
> tokens are forbidden."

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Whoever downvoted it -> please explain why. And if you can give some input related to the question please do so. Thanks

Comment: Basically there is a best practice to call regional, rather than global, AAD endpoints. You enable it by setting [AZURE_REGIONAL_AUTHORITY_NAME](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/0c236664e59ad7cda2212a8cbb7cca79e500a1d7/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/EnvironmentVariables.cs#L31). However the regional AAD endpoints do not yet have full parity with the global ones, with encrypted tokens being a prominent exception. It looks like managed identities use that feature explicitly, which is probably the cause for the error above: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/21937.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason (maybe someone can explain why) after removing .default from the scope it worked.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, I don't see how that would be related. BTW next time I suggest you file an issue in the Azure SDK's GH repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues.